# ANSI what does this sequence mean?

Tags: go, ansi-colors

I know that this is [ANSI color sequence](http://www.bluesock.org/~willg/dev/ansi.html), but what does this mean?

```
BLUE = "\x1b[38;05;4m"
```

`\x1b` is escape (ASCII 27)

What is `38`?
What is `05`?
and What is `4m`?

It seems there are no such thing on the list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah I see, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) has more complete reference

`38` is `Reserved for extended set foreground color`

`05` is `next is the color index`

`4` is `color blue`

Comment: Meanwhile, the "m" is the ANSI Code terminator.